# Best practice for handling SMS/email convergence

Tags: email, sms

I'm writing a school administration software package, but it strikes me that many developers will face this same issue: when communicating with users, should you use email or SMS or try to combine them?

A previous version of this question was closed for being too subjective. The answers will be somewhat subjective but I do think this is a good question, topical and not yet debated widely.  I'll try to narrow it down as much as I can:

1. Is it feasible to give users the choice of email versus SMS, and have the same business logic apply to both, with the help of a long form and short form message template?
2. Do users get annoyed when receiving the same message over SMS and email?
3. Is it common to present administrators with a single report listing message delivery failures combining both SMS and email?
4. Are there significant numbers of users who prefer to be contacted via facebook rather than SMS or email?
5. Is there a best practice for all this stuff?
6. Is there a place on the web where this stuff has been debated?
7. Are there any reputable commentators who have made predictions about the future of all this stuff?

I'm particularly interested in hearing from developers who have already grappled with these questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it feasible to give users the choice of email versus SMS, and have the same business logic apply to both, with the help of a long form and short form message template?

Yes, you can implement logic for the user to select which methods of communication he would like to use

> Do users get annoyed when receiving the same message over SMS and email?

ABSOLUTELY! Unless the user has set up to receive messages in both the formats

> Is it common to present administrators with a single report listing message delivery failures combining both SMS and email?

Yes

> Are there significant numbers of users who prefer to be contacted via facebook rather than SMS or email?

Cannot comment on this, YMMV depending on the usage of the site, the target user group etc. You site stats & trends over a period of time will help fine-tune this aspect.

> Is there a best practice for all this stuff?

Sure, see a lot of sites which give opt-in/opt-out options for getting communications from the sites. The tendency to spam/flood inboxes with a lot of email should be avoided & the user should be able to set how little/much data should be sent to him & in what format. Google is your friend here, there are tons of articles out there on different aspects.

> Is there a place on the web where this stuff has been debated?

I am sure you will find all sorts of legal & other details around this aspect, google is your friend on this item